# How to iterate array on GeoJSON to draw polygon dynamically in react-leaflet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sql-server, leaflet, react-leaflet

I'm currently working on project that user draw a polygon and save that data on SQL server and load that data from SQL to show on leaflet page.

What I did so far is, saving drawing data on sql server and load it, having this format.

```
const MapGeoInfo = () => {
    const [geoJsonData, setGeojsonData] = useState<any>([]);
    const [geoJsonKey, addToGeoJsonKey] = useState(1)

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const resp: any = await getGeoFenceMaster();
            const geoData = [];

            if (resp?.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 0; i < resp.length; i++) {
                    geoData.push([resp[i]['lng'], resp[i]['lat']]);
                }
            }

            var data = resp,
                hash = Object.create(null),
                result = data.reduce(function (r: any, a: any) {
                    if (!hash[a.type]) {
                        hash[a.type] = { type: a.type, data: [] };
                        r.push(hash[a.type]);
                    }
                    hash[a.type].data.push({ lat: a.lat, lng: a.lng });
                    return r;
            }, []);

            setTestval(data);
            setGeojsonData(geoData);
            addToGeoJsonKey(geoJsonKey + 1);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <GeoJSON
            key={geoJsonKey}
            data={{
                "type": "Polygon",
                "coordinates": [geoJsonData],
            }}
            style={{ color: "#1FFFF9", weight: 4, opacity: 5 }}
        >
        </GeoJSON>
    )
};

export default MapGeoInfo;
```

So what I did first was, after getting data I made an array and store at "geoData" with push. But I just realized there's no such thing to make difference each polygon and when I show it on GeoJson, it just showed like this.
[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVBIm.jpg)

So I tried to make separate first on these data by type (name of each polygon) using hash following format.

[how hash look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBaT3.png)

Now I think this data format would work and now I need to work on how to iterate this onto GeoJson.
I'm new to both react and leaflet so keep researching for a week now to work on this but still haven't find any solution.

I'm thinking to use map() to iterate GeoJson and I'm working on it but not sure.

---- edit

I attached the image if resp looks like. So it has "type" "name" "lat" and "lng" So all the polygon should be separate by "type"
[resp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maNAd.png)

```
1: {type: 'A', name: 'A1', lat: 32.99253926199695, lng: -84.09759521484376}
2: {type: 'A', name: 'A1', lat: 32.99253926199695, lng: -83.00445556640625}
3: {type: 'A', name: 'A1', lat: 32.44952057251957, lng: -83.00445556640625}
4: {type: 'B', name: 'B1', lat: 32.86113232281097, lng: -84.5452880859375}
5: {type: 'B', name: 'B1', lat: 32.32427558887655, lng: -84.24041748046876}
6: {type: 'B', name: 'B1', lat: 31.98711230651552, lng: -83.46862792968751}
7: {type: 'B', name: 'B1', lat: 33.15364887320584, lng: -83.74603271484375}
8: {type: 'B', name: 'B1', lat: 33.10764766506478, lng: -84.39697265625}
9: {type: 'B', name: 'B1', lat: 33.01326987686983, lng: -84.90509033203126}
10: {type: 'B', name: 'B1', lat: 32.58384932565662, lng: -85.00122070312501}
11: {type: 'B', name: 'B1', lat: 32.33123819794542, lng: -84.64141845703126}
12: {type: 'C', name: 'C1', lat: 31.61830484385287, lng: -84.62768554687501}
13: {type: 'C', name: 'C1', lat: 32.02903481873586, lng: -84.62768554687501}
14: {type: 'C', name: 'C1', lat: 32.02903481873586, lng: -83.68011474609376}
15: {type: 'C', name: 'C1', lat: 31.61830484385287, lng: -83.68011474609376}
16: {type: 'D', name: 'D1', lat: 33.05701850585396, lng: -82.84790039062501}
17: {type: 'D', name: 'D1', lat: 33.23179557851464, lng: -82.84790039062501}
18: {type: 'D', name: 'D1', lat: 33.23179557851464, lng: -82.66937255859376}
19: {type: 'D', name: 'D1', lat: 33.05701850585396, lng: -82.66937255859376}
```

Comment: Hi RunningKanguru and welcome to SO. I think you should look into creating more complex GeoJSON structures. [See this gist](https://gist.github.com/wavded/1200773?short_path=99c1af9) for an example of a more rich dataset looks like. The set is composed of *Features* where each Feature has a *type* that describes what the coordinates of a feature should create, like polygons, circles, lines, etc. A more in depth specification would be the [RFC 7946](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#appendix-A) documentation. If you need any help, then please share a sample of the `resp` value.

Comment: I attached image of `resp` value. So what I understand is, I need to create rich dataset from sql and not just put value on GeoJson? Thank you for comment.

Comment: If possible, please include the `resp` value (or at least part of it) as text. That makes it easier to inspect. And yes, currently you have your GeoJSON formatted in a way where there is one feature - a Polygon. But what you need is a *FeatureCollection* which Leaflet can loop over, where each *Feature* is a group of coordinates that create a shape.

Comment: Ok I put resp as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enrich your data with GeoJSON formatting. The snippet below loops over the array of your SQL entries and groups them by the `type` property. After that the grouped values are looped over again with `Array#map` to create [Feature Objects](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7946#section-3.2) for each group of coordinates. There we specify that each group of coordinates is a Polygon. Update the state by adding the features to the Feature Collection object.

**Sidenote**

This solution gives a lot of responsibility to the frontend to format the data in a usable way. You'll help yourself in the long run by storing the data in the format that you need it to be so that the frontend only has to implement the data.

```js
type FeatureCollection = {
    type: 'FeatureCollection';
    features: Feature[]
};

type Feature = {
    type: string;
    geometry: {
        type: string;
        coordinates: Coordinate[];
    };
};

type FeatureGroup = {
    string?: Coordinate[];
};

type Coordinate = [
    lat: number,
    lng: number
];
```

```js
const MapGeoInfo = () => {
  const [geoJsonData, setGeojsonData] = useState<FeatureCollection>({
    type: 'FeatureCollection',
    features: []
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const resp: any = await getGeoFenceMaster();

      const groupedData: FeatureGroup = resp.reduce((acc, cur) => {
        if (!acc[cur.type]) {
          acc[cur.type] = [];
        }

        acc[cur.type].push([cur.lat, cur.lng]);
        return acc;
      }, {});

      const features: Feature[] = Object.values(groupedData).map((coordinates) => ({
        type: 'Feature',
        geometry: {
          type: 'Polygon',
          coordinates
        }
      }));

      setGeojsonData(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        features
      }));
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);


  return (
    <GeoJSON
      data={geoJsonData}
      style={{ color: "#1FFFF9", weight: 4, opacity: 5 }}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had no idea what to start but I got it and it works now. It called featureObject...  Thanks I learned a lot